# How to create a wall using Design Automation API for Revit

Tags: revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

I am trying to create a wall using Design Automation API for Revit. How can I achieve this.

I am working on a project which creates walls based on excel file. 
First I convert the excel file to json and pass them as parameter to a Revit template file (.rte file) and the result output is a Revit file (.rvt) with the wall. This process happens in a loop based on the number of rows in the excel file.

I have achieved this task in the Revit API desktop addins, but I am unable to understand as to how this can be achieved in the Design Automation API for Revit.

I have followed the steps given in the link

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step1-convert-addin/

But I am unable to understand how send the template file (.rte) to the Forge API to output the .rvt file. Can multiple revit files be returned through the API?

Can someone please guide me in the right direction to create a wall

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer code samples for SketchIt app. It takes json inputs for Wall locations and creates a Revit file with Walls in them.

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/more-learning-resources/
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-nodejs-sketchIt
https://s3.amazonaws.com/revitio/documentation/SketchIt.mp4